# I keep on getting a "BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe" when I run this, and I don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

It seems the broken pipe error is happening when I'm printing st, and when I delete that, it happens at when I print l, then po.

```
def rearrangedString(s):
    out = ""
    st = ""
    stt = ""
    st = [char for char in s]  
    aaaaaa = len(set(st))
    print(st)
    po = []
    l = [""] * 101
    while len(st) > 0:
        for k in range(0, aaaaaa):
            j = st[k]
            po.append(j)
            for o in range(0, len(st)):
                if st[o] == j and o != k:
                    l[o] = st[o]
                    st[o] = ""
                    print(st)
                    print(l)
                    print(po)
        st = l
        aaaaaa = len(st)
        ko = ""
        out += "".join(sorted(po))
        po = []
        l = [""]*101
        print(out)
    print(out)
    return out
```

Comment: Your code is a bit hard to understand, can you point out what is this algorithm goal and what each part does?

Comment: what is s? is it really a `string`? Broken pipe errors is mostly due to file operations (reading too many lines) are you sure this is the part of your code responsible for this error?

Comment: The goal for this is to find the first occurrence of each distinct letter in st, then to sort them alphabetically and add them to out and remove them from st.  This repeats until st it empty. (and yes the input s is always a string)

Comment: Running you code with "abc" as argument run forever, not reproducing your broken pipe error, I cannot help you more like that, you should correct your code before so we can get idea of how your code is supposed to work : rename your variable with explicit names

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There re other useful infomation.

Comment: instead of `st = [char for char in s] ` you can simply do `st = list(s)`. You could use better names for variables. Name should describe what is in variable. It helps to understand code.

Comment: how big is `st` in `print(st)`? Do you get it from stream/pipe like `cat file | python script.py` ? Or maybe you get it from socket ? Or maybe you run it as subprocess using `PIP` ? All of them may use "pipe" to send data and they can close this pipe.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking a question on stack and I haven't been coding for that long :/